# How to add HyperLink without using anchor tag and hyperLink class In Java to set in Excel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a String value which will set the hyperlink text in Excel.
This string is been implemented using the URL which is been fetched from DB and trying to populate in a string.
But when I am printing the values in Excel it is printing
`=HYPERLINK("https://aphit-apo-prd-images.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/signatures/7121031286405333_161143194_signature_IKnC2PrFajWg05zcOqtPYWBojiB0kq9Wm10S_%2Boh2jbnxTinCHoovg2azHwmq6yL.jpg?20230314060753","Click to view signature")`
rather than showing only link like -> [Click to view signature](https://stackoverflow.com)

It is showing only text you can check scenarios image for reference.

I tried implementing ->

```
 if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(stringVal)) {
                            stringVal = "=HYPERLINK(" + "\"" + stringVal + "\",\"Click to view signature\")";
                            columnValueLst.add(stringVal);
                        }
```

But the when I am viewing in Excel it is showing like the below Image

[Current Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vloEE.png)

[Expected Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET4CI.png)

Comment: replace comma `,` with semicolon `;`! (between (Excel!)function arguments:) (`"\",\"Click` to `"\";\"Click`)